# ¿Como puedo quitar el espacio entre dos div?

Tags: html, css, html5

Este espacio en negro, pensaba que era una línea y se podía quitar fácil, pero es un espacio.

Quiero saber  como unir los tres `div` abajo con los 3 botones de arriba, así se va el espacio...

[image: esta es mi problema]

Este es el código

```css
.body {
  background: black;
}

.row-h-f-v {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgb(235, 231, 231);
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
}

.ul-h-f-v .il-h-f-v {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: auto;
}

.btn-h-f-v {
  width: 13rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgb(235, 231, 231);
}

.btn-h-f-v:hover {
  background: rgb(207, 201, 201);
}

.cosas {
  display: flex;
}

.container-left {
  width: 75rem;
  height: 100rem;
  background: white;
}

.container-center {
  width: 200rem;
  height: 100rem;
  background: yellowgreen;
}

.container-right {
  width: 75rem;
  height: 100rem;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">

  <div class="row-h-f-v">

    <ul class="ul-h-f-v">

      <li class="il-h-f-v">
        <div>
          <a href="" class="a-h-f-v"><button class="btn-h-f-v">Historias</button></a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="il-h-f-v">
        <div>
          <a href="" class="a-h-f-v"><button class="btn-h-f-v">Fotos</button></a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="il-h-f-v">
        <div>
          <a href="" class="a-h-f-v"><button class="btn-h-f-v">Videos</button></a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cosas">

    <div class="container-left ">

    </div>

    <div class="container-center "></div>
    <div class="container-right "></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el navegador algunos tag por defecto tienen estilos pre-establecidos.

En tu caso solo tenes que sacarle el `margin` al `ul.ul-h-f-v`

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.body {
  background: black;
}

.row-h-f-v {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgb(235, 231, 231);
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
}

.ul-h-f-v .il-h-f-v {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: auto;
}

/* ACA sacamos el margen al ul */
.ul-h-f-v {
  margin: 0;
}

.btn-h-f-v {
  width: 13rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgb(235, 231, 231);
}

.btn-h-f-v:hover {
  background: rgb(207, 201, 201);
}

.cosas {
  display: flex;
}

.container-left {
  width: 75rem;
  height: 100rem;
  background: white;
}

.container-center {
  width: 200rem;
  height: 100rem;
  background: yellowgreen;
}

.container-right {
  width: 75rem;
  height: 100rem;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
  <div class="row-h-f-v">
    <ul class="ul-h-f-v">
      <li class="il-h-f-v">
        <div>
          <a href="" class="a-h-f-v"><button class="btn-h-f-v">Historias</button></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="il-h-f-v">
        <div>
          <a href="" class="a-h-f-v"><button class="btn-h-f-v">Fotos</button></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="il-h-f-v">
        <div>
          <a href="" class="a-h-f-v"><button class="btn-h-f-v">Videos</button></a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cosas">
    <div class="container-left "></div>
    <div class="container-center "></div>
    <div class="container-right "></div>
  </div><!-- ACA Te falta cerrar este div -->
</body>
```

Comment: Oye amigo gracias, ya lo probe y me funciono a la perfecion!!!!

Comment: OOO okok ya la marque, muchas gracias!!!!